# Byte Buddy: Annotation and Class<?>[] property with a byte buddy class

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Using ByteBuddy, I need create a new class with an annotation. This annotation has a Class[] property. I set the value using a class creating with Byte buddy

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<?>[] configuration() default {};
}
```

My class with annotation:

```
final Class<?> configClass = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(Object.class)
    .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(MyAnnotation.class)
        .defineTypeArray("configuration", myConfigClass)
        .build())
    .make()
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .getLoaded();
```

But this doesn't work, there is no annotation on the class. It works when I use a not byte buddy created class.

Here is my byte buddy created class :

```
final Class<? extends BasicConfig> myConfigClass = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(BasicRibbonConfig.class)
    .method(ElementMatchers.named("getTargetApplication"))
    .intercept(FixedValue.value(targetApplication))
    .make()
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .getLoaded();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was a class loader issue. I changed the configuration:

```
.load(ribbonConfig.getClassLoader(), INJECTION)
```